# Google Cloud Platform Storage error: "Locked Domain Expired" when trying to access my storage items

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cdn

I am currently hosting some static .css, .js, .tff, and image resources for my site in the google cloud platform storage buckets. I am able to access these resources for up to approximately 20 minutes after uploading them. After about 20 or so minutes I get a 401 error message when I try to access them that says:

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"lockedDomainExpired","message":"Locked Domain Expired"}],"code":401,"message":"Locked Domain Expired"}}

From the GCP site:

> lockedDomainExpired: When downloading content from a cookie-authenticated site, e.g., using the Storage Browser, the response will redirect to a temporary domain. This error will occur if access to said domain occurs after the domain expires. Issue the original request again, and receive a new redirect.

I'm not really sure what this means in the context of how I'm trying to use GCP storage buckets? Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you click on a link to an object in the developer console it generates a URL that is only valid for a short period of time.  I suspect you are copying this URL into your site rather than using the publicly accessible URL.

Assuming the objects are publicly readable you should be able to use this URL format instead.

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick! The links seem to be working for longer than 20 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

By opening the link of the object and quickly select the tab that opens, if we take a screen or select the tab you can see the real url of the object, which is what we are looking for.

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/<segment>/<path-file>/<file>
```

Where:

- `<segment>` is the name of the segment
- `<path file>` is the path of the file within the segment
- `<file>` es el nombre del archivo con la extensión incluida

Note that the screen was taken before the page finished loading and generated the temporary url. However the base URL does not work for a web service therefore instead of using `storage.cloud.google.com` **we have to use** `storage.googleapis.com` y checkear que en la pestaña de la URL aparezca el icono de Cloud Storage (esto nos dará un indicio que la url nos funcionará)

[image: Real URL while the page loads]

Here you can see the hierarchy of paths and files

[image: hierarchy of paths and files]

Characters that are after the file extension can be ignored

**Do not forget to activate the public link check if you are consuming a web service**